# If next line does not contains text, then delete line

Tags: if-statement, awk

I have a json file and using jq I am outputting the following.

```
      "network": "8.8.8.8/32",
        "firewall",
      "network": "8.8.8.7/32",
      "network": "8.8.8.9/32",
        "firewall",
      "network": "8.8.8.10/24",
      "network": "8.8.8.11/32",
        "firewall",
```

What I need to do is only show networks that contain a firewall. I would like to pipe this out to sed or awk to accomplish this but I haven't had much luck.

So basically if below line does not contains firewall, then delete line.

Expected output

```
      "network": "8.8.8.8/32",
        "firewall",
      "network": "8.8.8.9/32",
        "firewall",
      "network": "8.8.8.11/32",
        "firewall",
```

Some stuff I was trying but no luck

```
 cat file.json | jq '.items[].networks[] | {data:[{network:.network,devices:[.configs[].locations[].devices[] | select(.id | contains("firewall")).id]}]} | awk '/network/ {while (/network/ && getline>0) ; next} 1'
```

Am I going to have to pipe this to a file to make it easier?

Comment: Show the `jq`.  Probably you want to add a filter in `jq` rather than post-processing with awk.

Comment: Alot of nesting going on. I couldn't figure out how to get it done in the jq.

cat file.json | jq '.items[].networks[] | {data:[{network:.network,devices:[.configs[].locations[].devices[] | select(.id | contains("firewall")).id]}]}'

Comment: If you're ever again considering using `getline` then please read http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline to understand when/how to use it.

Comment: Please add your JSON file to your question (no comment).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Avoid `getline()`, use something like

```
| awk '/network/ {n=$0} /firewall/ { printf("%s\n%s\n", n, $0)}'
```